# Buttons mouse effects in windows store apps / WinRT?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have some tiles layed out as buttons in my app. Im not that good at xaml and hope someone here can guide or show how i come around making them behave alittle like the tiles in the start screen of windows.

I have  with some template set. How can i add the little border when mouse is moved over it and how do i make it look like it gets pushed down when clicked.

my button is just a sqare box with a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the Control template for Button. And add an additional border which should appear on Pointer over state. Write your own animation in Visual State manager to achieve this. To make this more easier just open your project in Expression Blend. Right click the button and choose edit template. the default template will fell into resources, so that you can just modify.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908.aspx

To perform a push effect, need to animate Scale Transform in pointer pressed state.

Regards,

Comment: I have added visual state grops and states with transitions but i feel like i am missing something. How to trigger them

Comment: In case of Button, you don't need to trigger them explicitly. But in case if you want to add a new state, you can use the method VisualStateManager.GotoState() to trigger them in code behind.

Comment: I just discovered that it works when the right names are given to the states. Just need to find a list over available states (pointerpressed) didnt exist :)